# Acer AC713 MONTIOR

Tags: acer-aspire-one

I have an Acer AC713 CRT.

After trying to play a game on my PC I get the error:

> OUT OF RANGE H:75,1KHZ ; V:60,1HZ

Can you tell my how can I solve this problem?

Comment: what OS? have you tried the monitor with another computer?

Answer (score 1):

The game possibly has its own configuration file and it has a default / saved resolution that is higher than your monitor can handle.

It would be easier if you say what OS you use, but if I was you, look in the following:

1. First look in the start menu to see if the application has any configuration utility that can be launched outside the game,
2. Then look in the program folder for any setting file
3. Look in the my documents folder for any settings files
4. If using Vista / 7, check in User > Appdata > Local > VirtualStore, this is were UAC redirects read/writes to.

There could be other places, but these should be the main ones.